# Illegal mix of collations when the fields in the database have the same collation

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was getting the following error message:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General er
ror: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and     (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=''
```

the query looks like this:

```
SELECT
name,
address,
email,
@userid:=(user) AS user_id,
(select count(id) from messages where user_id=@userid and thread_start='1')
 as counter,
 (select group_concat(search) from saved_search where user_id=@userid ) as area
FROM
useraccount
WHERE
flag = '1'
```

The issue was fixed by adding COLLATION

```
SELECT
name,
address,
email,
@userid:=(user) AS user_id,
(select count(id) from messages where user_id=@userid COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci and thread_start='1')
 as counter,
 (select group_concat(search) from saved_search where user_id=@userid     COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ) as area
FROM
useraccount
WHERE
flag = '1'
```

My question is, why, when the user field, and the user_id fields all had the same collation when I look in the database, is specifying the collation necessary?

Just to make it all the more confusing, in MySQL workbench, the query works, but in PHP/PDO it errors out.

Comment: Just don't do stuff like that. use `where messages.user_id = useraccount.user`. "Hero code" often has side effects.